# Mutiple OUs in Win2k8 pGina configuration

Tags: windows-server-2008, redhat, ldap

I have pGina installed to a Windows Server 2008 box that is using a RHDS LDAP for authentication. So far I have it working so that if we use only one organizational unit and do not care about permissions/rights then it will authenticate the user.

**What I need...**

I need to be able authenticate a user using a list of OUs (they would only be located in one OU but we have many) and additionally use the group of a given user in the RHDS to define whether they are allowed administrative access to the Windows box.

Answer (score 0):

Is your ldap tree nested?

If so, maybe you could use the 'search for dn' section in the authentication tab of the ldap plugin to specify multiple base searches (search context):
 ou=group,dc=example,dc=org
 ou=another_group,dc=example,dc=org
(these are allowed ous)

If you ldap tree is flat you need to craft a filter:
    (|(ou=group)(ou=another_group))
to be inserted in the 'search filter' text form in the authentication tab.

To grant administrative access, the gateway tab of the ldap plugin provides a straighforward solution.

[docs for ldap plugin](http://pgina.org/docs/v3.1/ldap.html)